# need to pivot data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

i have data in a table as here

[image: i have data in a table in the format below]

i'm trying to convert it into this format / desired output

[image: out put formate]

Any Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Check out the many questions regarding [Oracle and pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+pivot)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a relational structure, because the columns within a row don't really relate to each other.  For that reason, this type of transformation is often better done at the application level.

That said, you can do this in Oracle.  One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select col1,
       max(case when col3 = 'CAT1' then col2 end) as cat1,
       max(case when col3 = 'CAT2' then col2 end) as cat2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1, col3 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1, seqnum
order by col1, seqnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PIVOT:

```
select col1, cat1, cat2
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col2) as rn
  from t
)
pivot (min(col2) for (col3) in ('CAT1' as "CAT1", 'CAT2' as "CAT2"))
order by rn;
```

[image]

[LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hdp0ldb72uge6realkvm5pgyd)